# How can i create the custom button to the rails_admin As I button will popup with asking to select tow option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, rails-admin

I am newbee to ruby on rails

I am working on to the rails admin Dashbord.

I want to add the custom Button to my edit page

I want custom button to be get add so i able to import data from other sites api Using Ajax

https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1468591_673129479393640_1655771510_n.jpg

Also suggest me good sites fro jquery ajax using ruby function call from jquery.

Thank 
And sorry for my very bad English.

Comment: and thanks for no ans fuoooooooooo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a search i found the solution
I need to use that 
https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import

in gem file i need to include it
gem "rails_admin_import", :git => "https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import.git"

as it dose not support **mongoid** it support **active record**